# Private app API using 'curl'

Tags: api, curl, private, shopify

I am trying to use `curl` and private app API and have successed to access to my shop but got an error message to modify current product using `curl` in PHP. Below is the code I used

(I put xml file as input.xml which included modify detail and tried sku using product i.d)
Is there any where keep modifying more than 250 product on one click?

```
//php
curl -v -X PUT -d @input.xml -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'(<-- this is line 2) 
'https://myapikey:mypassword@myshopdomain/admin/products/product_id.xml'

// and i got this error message 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/s/o/n/song2660/html/curltest.php on line 2"
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the xml file you're using too.